# Observing session create-destroy events in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-session

I am using "express-session" and "memorystore". I want to log session create and destroy activities. My solution is, taking a snapshot of the current "sessionStorage" and a while later, compare it with the current "sessionStorage" and based on the differance, report session created, destroyed activites.

```
let sessionSnapshot;
app.get('/',
function (req, res, next) {
    let currentSnapshot = req.sessionStore;
    let difference = sessionSnapshot.filter(x => !currentSnapshot.includes(x));
    // Report create/destroy activities based on difference.
});
```

Is there any other places / callbacks that I can track session create and destroy events ?
I am using "passport" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey patch this function https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/memory.js#L93-L96

```
const MemoryStore = require('./node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js');

const originalSet = MemoryStore.prototype.set;
MemoryStore.prototype.set = function set(sessionId, session, callback) {
  console.log('saving session with id %s and parameters', sessionId, session);
  return originalSet.call(this, sessionId, session, callback);
}

// for destroy
const original = MemoryStore.prototype.destroy;
// patched function
MemoryStore.prototype.destroy = function(sessionId, callback) {
  console.log('destroying session with id %s', sessionId);
  return original.call(this, sessionId, callback)
}
```

and then, you can use this patched memory store in application

```
app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 },
    store: new MemoryStore({
      checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
    }),
    resave: false,
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```

UPD: probably, patching MemoryStore.prototype.touch in similiar way саn be usefull too

Comment: "set" is not a good way to catch session create events. It gets called many times. However, when a session is inserted, it can be compared with a unique cache to see if its a new session. Thankyou !